# Sub not ending after unloading userform and activating worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, userform, worksheet, activation

I'm using Userform1 to make 1 worksheet invisible (coverP) and making another worksheet visible (RstVer).

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()    'sub in userform1
Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Debug.Print "1"
Application.Visible = True: Debug.Print "2"
RstVer.Visible = xlSheetVisible: Debug.Print "3"
RstVer.Activate: Debug.Print "4"
coverP.Visible = xlSheetHidden: Debug.Print "5"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True: Debug.Print "6"
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Debug.Print "7"
Unprotect "password": Debug.Print "8"
Range("K9") = CStr(stfList.Cells(100, 100).Value): Debug.Print "9"
Range("D37").End(xlUp).Select: Debug.Print "10"
Protect "password": Debug.Print "11"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True: Debug.Print "12"
End Sub
```

After clicking CommandButton1, coverP was hidden and RstVer was visible, but my workbook behaves like ScreenUpdating was disabled.  After examining the developer, I found that sub (not sure which one) was still running.  In the immediate window, I got 1 2 3 4 5 6, but not the other numbers I was expecting.  Can you enlighten me on this?

Comment: Is `Sub Worksheet_Activate()` on the form ? If so, are you expecting it to be called with `RstVer.Activate` ?

Comment: @CDP1802 Sub Worksheet_Activate() is on the worksheet.  I want it to be called everytime the worksheet activates.  I activate this worksheet sometimes just working on the workbook by clicking on it.

Comment: The activate event is not trigged if the worksheet is already the active one. A possible fix would be to activate another sheet first.

Comment: I think I'd asked a silly question.  My problem was because the form was shown not under vbmodeless...the setting was an accident!